# Connect Manager fails to download with SSL handshake error

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, ssl, downloader

Today, my Magento Downloader won't work. It worked for installing extensions previously, but today I get: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure. It seems the issue is on Magento Connect, but I don't see other reports of the issue.

Magento 1.9.1

Comment: Is your server still running sslv3?  Do you have access to your own web server config?  If so you can try disabling sslv3 and switching to tlsv1.

Comment: I have the same problem ! With my magento 1.9.1
It was working before and I changed nothing on the server.

Comment: “This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.”

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: These comments may not be "answers", but they do point to a wider problem than just me. My dev setup worked just fine prior to yesterday, and then I was receiving this error. I will look at my server setup, per the suggestions, but that does not explain WHY it previously worked, then did not.

Comment: anyone have fixed this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have received a version of the: `error: 14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure!`
error while trying to install a Magento Connect extension, it's because Magento turned off SSLv# on Magento Connect, but curl is still trying to connect with SSLv3.

Here is a solution and a patch file I came up with a few days ago. I wrote a post about it on our blog and explaining how to patch it: https://www.dwdonline.com/blog/fix-magento-error14077410ssl-routinesssl23_get_server_hellosslv3-alert-handshake-failure.html

Comment: Perfection! Following your blog. Hoping this fix makes its way into the next release. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Glad it helped! It wouldn't let me post an answer earlier (had to get a higher reputation).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, for a temporary solution:
you can download the source files directly off of MagentoConnect using this tool:

http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

and then upload them manually!

Comment: While not a final answer, this helps tremendously. Thanks! (Unfortunately, I lack the "rep" to upvote this response)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, everything is fine on the my development site installed locally (running on MAMP) but nothing on the live website (centos w/cpanel & whm)

here is the apache config

- SSLv2   Disabled
- SSLv3   Disabled
- TLS 1   Enabled
- TLS 1.1 Enabled
- TLS 1.2 Enabled