# Magento 1.9.2 Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1

Tags: magento-connect, extensions, ce-1.9.2.0

Just tried to load an extension through magento connect and had the error "Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1", the extension was Subcategories Grid/List by apptrian.

Have tried a few more extensions and the same error comes up.  Magento 1.9.2

Anyone have a clue on how to approach this issue?

Comment: When is an upgrade not an upgrade? When Magento includes a downloader that's expecting SSL on a brand new version release when they've shut it off on the server. One of those "don't modify core code" things where you have to modify core code so it will work.

Answer (score 51):

I use "CENTOS PHP 5.4.43 cURL 7.19.7"

In downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php, try changing:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

to

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

Comment: worked for me on the latest Magento upgrade

Comment: worked for me on 1.9.2.2

Comment: Worked for me on 1.9.1.0

Comment: Worked again on 1.9.2.3 - see my answer at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73861/solution-to-magento-downloader-1-9-2-unknown-cipher-list/99350#99350

Comment: Worked on 1.9.2.4

Comment: Can someone let me know how to find this folder? I am using putty with `find . downloader` and it can't be found. also tried `Mage`

Comment: On magento 1.9.2.1, this bring to a new error: `CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Cm_RedisSession failed: TCP connection reset by peer`

Answer (score 5):

In file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php I changed the code

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

to

```
if(isset($var)){

   $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');

}
```

and problem will be solved for now.

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs while trying to install a Magento Connect extension because Magento turned off SSLv3 on Magento Connect, but curl is still trying to connect with SSLv3.

In downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php

After:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

add:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

It looks like your issue is related to:
[Connect Manager fails to download with SSL handshake error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57963/connect-manager-fails-to-download-with-ssl-handshake-error)