# Check for updates didn't work in Magento Connect Manager ver. 1.9.3.0

Tags: upgrade, magento-connect-manager, linux

I want to upgrade version magento from 1.9.3.0 to 1.9.3.1 via Magento Connect Manager. I press button Check for updates but on Debian 7 server it's do nothing. When i copy this on local computer it's work correctly. I check solution [Solution to Magento Downloader 1.9.2 unknown cipher list](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73861/solution-to-magento-downloader-1-9-2-unknown-cipher-list/137401#137401) but not find this string in my version.

Answer (score 2):

modified this file: /downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php (line 371)

```
protected function makeRequest($method, $uri, $params = array(), $isAuthorizationRequired = false, $https = true)
    {
```

to

```
protected function makeRequest($method, $uri, $params = array(), $isAuthorizationRequired = false, $https = false)
    {
```

Comment: This code fixed for me. Now I can easily upgrade my magento old version.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with 1.9.3.1

As stated in the release notes you can't upgrade to 1.9.3.1 via the Magento Connect Manager: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1931