# Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?

Tags: magento-1, security, patches, supee-8788

The latest Magento 1 security patch SUPEE-8788 contains [17 APPSEC updates](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-8788), so it is very important to apply it as soon as possible. On the other hand, there are many potential backward compatibility breaks, and given the history of patches over the last year I would not apply it carelessly.

<del>Good thing is that this time there are no frontend templates involved, so it looks like we don't need to patch all our themes.</del> This is only true for Magento 1.8 or higher.

Nonetheless: Did you encounter any compatibility problems or bugs after applying the patch?

Comment: "there are no frontend templates involved" - is not correct for older Magento versions. For example the 1.7.0.2 patch changes 9 frontend/base/default template files .

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140571/supee-8788-and-supee-1533-how-to-approach dupes this one? Maybe bundle all the info here...

Comment: For anyone having problems with the .swf updates of the patch, I simply removed lines 5951-9818 from the patch and manually removed the .swf files from `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media` - since that's all the patch was doing anyway.

Comment: not sure why but after 8788 installation on 1.8.0.0 , patch 7405 reports as NOT installed. while v1 and v1.1 was previously installed

Comment: Since there are some template changes for 1.7.0.2., (app/design/frontend/base/default/template.....)Do we still have to manually apply same changes for out theme files? even after patch, the website works fine and no known issues found with formkey.

Comment: New updated patch 8788 v2 has been released by Magento  https://www.magentocommerce.com/download#download1934

Comment: I tried both patching and upgrading my magento to 1.9.3,but magereport still shows that the patch supee8788 is not applied, and credit card hijack detected

Comment: @srinivas did you removed the media folder from this path skin/adminhtml/default/default ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a summary of what I (and others) encountered so far, I'm trying to keep it sorted, feel free to add or link anything that's missing, the post is a Community Wiki:

### Reasons for failed patch

If you see "ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully", look for "Hunk #1 FAILED" in the log messages to check at which file the patch failed.

- Apparently v2 of the patch for Magento 1.7 expects SUPEE-3941 to present **although it only exists for Magento 1.8 and 1.9**. If you are on Magento 1.7 and see errors related to files in `downloader`, download SUPEE-3941 for 1.8 and apply it on 1.7, it should work. See comment thread here: [Security Patch SUPEE 8788 problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141259/security-patch-supee-8788-problem/141275?noredirect=1)
- On Magento versions that have had SUPEE-1533 applied before, the patch fails at `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php` because the file is affected by both patches and SUPEE-8788 (incorrectly!) assumes that the unpatched version is present. **This is still true with version 2 of the patch!** Version 2 includes the changes from SUPEE-1533, so if you installed it before, you still have to revert it, but you don't have to manually apply it again afterwards.
- If you deleted or renamed the "downloader" directory, the patch will fail because it patches a file within the downloader. The easiest workaround is to restore the original downloader directory, apply the patch, then delete the directory again. Alternatively, you could also remove the instructions for `downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php` from the patch.
- Other "Hunk FAILED" messages are usually due to changes in core files or missing previous patches. Make sure all previous patches for your Magento version are installed and you did not make changes in core files.
- Another common problem is that the patch fails to delete `.swf` files because of their binary content. The error will look like this:

  ```
  checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
  Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
  Apply anyway? [n]
  Skipping patch.
  1 out of 1 hunk ignored
  ```

  or like this

  ```
  Patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf using Plan A...
  No such line 2 in input file, ignoring
  Empty context always matches.
  Hunk #1 failed at 0.
  1 out of 1 hunks failed while patching skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
  Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...
  The text leading up to this was:
  --------------------------
  ```

  or like this:

  ```
  Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
  /bin/patch: **** malformed patch at line 5790: ?rM]M??????&X㔮??v??Q;r?N?qJ??Y???I0?Y??4??'?????9?.??X?Ǒ?{??ax!G???I???q?u|????թ??????|
                                                 h??o?V@??|? ?g?H aꪭ??Ю???,I"?ğ????.??    yI?I\????)?X?
                       ?p???*?e?q?K8<DqD?H;|?
  ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
  ```

  Possible solutions are given in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140629/243) by @infabo. Downloading the patch directly to the system where I want to apply it, using curl as explained in https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/9bc45ec84028611d621e always worked for me, except when I tried it on Cygwin

**Advanced way to deal with failed patches:** @PeterOCallaghan suggested to comment out the dry-run line and manually deal with the *.rej files. This way the patch can partially be applied and if it fails to delete the swf files, you can do that manually. Or if it fails to update files in `downloader` because you deleted that directory, you can just ignore that.

> 1. `vi PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2016-10-11-06-54-44.sh` (or similar file name) change `_apply_revert_patch dry-run` to look like
>      `#_apply_revert_patch dry-run`
> 2. run the patch by issuing  `./PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2016-10-11-06-54-44.sh`
>
> That will patch your files
>
> 3. Comment `_apply_revert_patch` to `#_apply_revert_patch`
> 4. run the patch again, to add the `app/etc/app/etc/applied.patches.list` entry
> 5. grep for all .rej files with
>
>    `git status | grep *.rej`
> 6. manually work in those changes

### Issues after applying patch

#### Form keys

- For Magento versions prior to 1.8 there are changes in `frontend/base/default` templates. Make sure that you manually apply the same changes in your theme if it overrides these files

  More specifically, a form key has been added for frontend actions such as:

  - Removing an item from the wishlist
  - Deleting a customers address from the store view
  - Updating a quote item in your basket

  See [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140553/243) by @LukeRogers if you encounter problems with these actions.

#### Custom uploader

Unirgy_Rapidflow and other extensions with custom upload forms are not working anymore.

See [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140978/243) by @mpchadwick and comment by @lloiacono

> I fixed it by replacing `$this->getUploader()->getConfig()` with `$this->getUploader()->getUploaderConfig()` in `Unirgy_RapidFlow_Block_Adminhtml_Profile_Edit_Tab_Upload`

To find out if any of your extensions use this, you can run the following on the command line:

```
grep -R 'getUploader()->getConfig();' app/code/community
```

#### Reported error messages

- > PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function hash_equals()

  happens if you are on a PHP version prior to 5.6 and override `code/core/Mage/core/functions.php` in `code/local/Mage/core/functions.php` (which might be the case if you use Fishpig extensions). See [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140664/243) by @ClaudiuCreanga

---

### Problems solved in v2 of the patch

If you encounter any of these issues, you probably use version 1 of the patch ("v1" in the filename). Download the patch again to get "v2" which fixes these issues:

- There was a compatibility issue with SUPEE-3941 and `downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php`
- > 'Exception' with message 'Unsupported data type N' in /lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
- The patch for EE 1.14.2.0 accidently contained a new file test_oauth.php which you **should delete!** See [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140652/243) by @MatthiasZeis

Comment: Form key added when updating quote item in the basket is not something that has been added with SUPEE-8788 (not from 1.9.2.4 at least)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism at the very least the 1.13.0.1 patch adds form key validation to `Mage_Checkout_CartController::updatePostAction`, potentially other patch versions as well.

Answer (score 109):

### Important notes

Please note that **1.9.3 is different than 1.9.2.4 + SUPEE-8788.** Here's the diff between the two: https://gist.github.com/digitalpianism/14a15cd52baede0e5d600e8c653f33e9

Update October 14th: v2 of the patch has been released (see below) <del>As of October 13th, the patches for 1.5.x to 1.8.x have been taken down from the Magento website because of the incompatibility with previous patches (see below):</del>

https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788-AND-SUPEE-1533-Incompatible-Hunk-error/td-p/50434/highlight/false/page/2

### V3 of the patch

This new version is **only for Magento EE 1.13.0.x**

Apply the V3:

- revert SUPEE 1533 (if installed)
- install SUPEE 3941 (if not installed)
- install SUPEE 8788 v3

### V2 of the patch

Apply the V2:

- revert SUPEE 8788 v1
- revert SUPEE 1533 (if installed)
- install SUPEE 3941 (if not installed)
- install SUPEE 8788 v2

DemacMedia developed a useful bash script to automate the process above you can find it here: https://github.com/DemacMedia/magento-SUPEE8788-patcher

### Details of the patch

After digging into the patch here are the interesting parts (patching from 1.9.2.4):

- **`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader` has been replaced with `Mage_Uploader_Block_Multiple` so there's a full `Mage_Uploader` module which drops Flash support**. The old block is now deprecated and extends the new block.
- Still regarding the uploader, **the `Mage_Downloadable` module has been refactored to handle the new non-flash uploader.** It uses `Mage_Uploader_Block_Single` as the upload block instead of using templates.
- Following this change, t**he SWF files `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf`, `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf` and `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf` have been deleted.**
- **Address deletion controller is now protected with form key** directly via the `getDeleteUrl` from `Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Book`
- **Wishlist item removal controller is now protected with form key** via the `getRemoveUrl` from `Mage_Wishlist_Helper_Data`
- **Paypal Express payment method now ensures that the customer email used exists in Magento when checking out and registering a new user.** (understand: the new user is created before the new quote is processed)
- **The payment methods using cURL/HTTP Client now have `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` set to 2 (was 0 before) and the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` flag is now added to the cURL calls.** The Verify Peer flag can be enable/disable via the payment method configuration via the Enable SSL Verification dropdown.
- **`Mage_Http_Client_Curl` now has `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` set to true (was false before)**, beware if you have any custom module using it.
- Max dimensions for product pictures are now configurable in the config. NB: it can result in a funny error message if you upload too big images: [Disallowed file format in Magento 1.9.2.2 after patch upload](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/141989/2380)

### Known SUPEE-8788 v2 issues

- [Magento 1.9.2.0 SUPEE-8788 v2 Hunk #1 FAILED at 91 after reverting SUPEE-1533](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/141036/2380)
- Patch can't be applied on PayPal Express model: [Magento 1.9.2.2 SUPEE-8788 v2 Hunk #1 FAILED](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/141142/2380)
- Coïncidence not patch related <del>Emails stopped being sent on 1.8 : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/141799/2380 and [Security patch 8788 V2 problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/141869/2380)</del>
- Backward incompatible change when calling the `getConfig()` method from the uploader block: [Issue in Admin Panel after SUPEE Patch 8788 installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/142006/2380)

### Known SUPEE-8788 v1 issues

- Update: the v2 of the patch fixes that issue (see above)<del>**Conflict between SUPEE-1533 and SUPEE-8788**, [possible (hacky) workaround here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140558/2380) . A [less hacky solution here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140576/2380)</del>
- Update: v2 of the patch fixes that issue <del>**`Unsupported data type N` error** in `/lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php` in 1.9.1.0 and possibly earlier versions when patch is applied. fix here: https://gist.github.com/balloz/ceaf5feb5ac66caaa82342441d32aa88</del>
- Update: the v2 of the patch fixes that issue <del>Possible conflict with SUPEE-3941: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140696/2380</del>
- **Issue with OS X: `Illegal Byte Sequence`** : [SUPEE-8788 on OSX - illegal byte sequence](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/140632/2380)
- **Malformed patch (probably bue to the binary sequence in the patch)**: [Magento 1.9.2.4 patch SUPEE-8788 malformed patch at line 5790](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/140640/2380)
- **Inclusion of a `test_oauth.php` file with EE patch**, [don't push that file to prod](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140652/2380)
- **Possible login issue on EE related to `Enterprise_Pci`** : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140577/2380
- **Problem if you edit the patch file as it contains binary files encapsulated**, use this method if you need to edit: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140575/2380
- In case **you have an `app/code/local` version of `Mage/Core/functions.php` you'll have issue with the new `hash_equals` function**: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140664/2380
- Good to know that **there is some templates change involved regarding form_key for Magento prior to 1.8**
- Possible issue on 1.5.1.0 with `downloader/Maged/View.php` : [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 failing at downloader/Maged/View.php (M1 v1.5.1.0)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/140742/2380)
- Incase you removed/renamed the `downloader` folder: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140631/2380

### Known 1.9.3.0 issues

Edit: as the list is getting long and it's pretty much off-topic in this answer (as not SUPEE-8788 related) you can refer to this post for the list of known 1.9.3.0 issues: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140826/2380

Comment: Hi, It shows me error as per given in link
http://screencast.com/t/eZ5WqnDww
What to do?

Comment: Thanks for the extensive list! One question: are you sure that the fulltext search issue applies to the SUPEE-8788 patch? I can't find any changes related to this functionality.

Comment: @MageDev please refer to the third comment in the question ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism ok, So, i need to delete code from patch file and also remove that file from directory too.

Comment: @AadMathijssen only on 1.9.3 actually ;)

Comment: If the product uploader does not work after successfully applying the patch and you are using the popular CreareSEO plugin then this fix will need to be applied also https://github.com/adampmoss/CreareSEO/pull/78

Comment: I noticed you mentioned "Paypal Express payment method now ensures that the customer email used exists in Magento." Does that mean that Guest cannot checkot with PayPal express? You must be registered user? Am I missing something.

Comment: @Icon I've updated my answer, it was indeed misunderstanding ;)

Comment: So now we have new patches for everything and essentially lost hours for nothing yesterday. This is gross incompetence and it is not the first time it is happening. Also the incompatibilities  could have been spotted during the first tests. Thanks for keeping us up to date Raphael.

Comment: Some third-party extension that used the old uploader are just broken after applying the patch. E.g. "Magic 360" is adding a tab into the backend product details tabs. After patching, you won't be able to see/edit your product details. I've noticed this issue to the extension developer on Magento connect (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magic-360-spin-your-product-images.html).

Comment: Hi I have installed in 1.9.0.0 it shows me (different line endings) error what can i do?
http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/141523/1927

Comment: Email issue posted above is not related to the patches. i deleted my original question about it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @RaphaelatDigitalPianism i have installed 8788 in 1.9.2.2 version but it shows some error in Catalog > Product Edit Page in Admin Panel. error is Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION' in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml on line 111. Can you help me out of this issue?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Can you please explain SUPEE 8788 v1 or SUPEE 8788 v2 means, is it magento 2.x or patch version because i don't find any patch version here https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Answer (score 30):

When applying the patch this error can happen:

```
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css
```

The 8788 patch contains binary content. As Magento does not provide any direct download links (I hate this policy ever since), you have to download the patch to your computer and upload it with an file-transfer application (like WinSCP on Windows) to your server. WinSCP for example will upload in TEXT-mode (WinSCP handles *.sh files as text by default).

So the workaround for this is, zip/tar the patch-file and unzip/untar again on the server. et voila.

---

Sorry I didn't have any way to answer this

1. Download the correct magento version (Eg: CE 1.9.1.0)
2. Replace the following files with downloaded location

skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf

3. Run the patch

Worked for me

---

Comment: Did you read the OPs question?

fschmengler asked: "Nonetheless: Did you encounter any compatibility problems or bugs AFTER applying the patch?"

I did encounter this problem WHILE applying the patch. I guess the sense of this thread is, to document the possible errors of SUPEE-8788. This includes - IMHO - problems with the patch itself too.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks! Is it best to do this for ALL future Magento patches too?

Comment: or you just dos2unix PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2016-10-11-07-03-46.sh

Comment: Generally it was not necessary before and I assume it will not be necessary in the future. I guess the uploader SWFs were the only binaries shipped with Magento 1.x - now they are gone. So I do not expect any issues like this one in the future again.

Comment: @fbtb no, you can not just dos2unix the patch-file. dos2unix will skip, because the patch contains binary content.

dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x00 found at line 5952
dos2unix: Skipping binary file PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_***.sh

Comment: and second. the issue is not related to unix/dos line endings. The problem is, file transfer clients upload the patch in text-mode. The hypothetical command would be called "convert-text-to-binary-back-again" and I don't know any tool that can do this. :D

Comment: @infabo i just did "dos2unix" and tried the solution via tar-ball both with the same result - allthough in my case the script throws errors in every line...

Comment: Yay, It's working fine with zip patch file and after uploading in server unzip file but yet there is one error
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
can't find file to patch at input line 4725
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

http://content.screencast.com/users/pITg/folders/Jing/media/afa43e5b-bf9d-4997-804b-cb00f85148c1/2016-10-13_1736.png

Comment: Should i create file manually in given directory?

Comment: When using FileZilla to upload the `.sh` patch file to your Magento root, set transfer type to `binary` before uploading the patch file. [Reference](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Data_Type)

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you for dragging me out of the magento patching rabbit hole!!! :)

Answer (score 26):

If you've previously applied SUPEE-1533 then the patch will fail on `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php.`

I solved this by...

1. Manually revert the changes introduced to that file by SUPEE-1533
2. Apply SUPEE-8788
3. Manually reintroduce the changes introduced to that file by SUPEE-1533

Removing the change from the SUPEE-8788 is dangerous because the patch file contains binary data and saving it in an editor can cause issues (another gotcha).

Comment: As I understand you reverted the original 1533 patch, installed SUPEE 8788, and then again installed 1533?? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: I am also having issue with FAILED HUNK at 28 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtml

Comment: In step 3 you mention to replace 8788 changes with 1533 after 8788 installs. Why can't we leave the 8788 changes in place? They seem to patch the same lines with a small code variation in DashboardController.php. Look down the thread I posted the compared changes between 1533 and 8788

Comment: I do wonder why, when we take the time to properly apply official incremental patches, we get penalised for doing so by having to make manual fixes when patches do not work when previously supplied patches have been applied.  A very odd approach.

Comment: My patch didn't fail as you mentioned. It just applied witout any errors. Magento version 1.9.2.4.

Comment: Most with versions below 1.9 that have SUPEE 1533 Installed, cannot instal the patch properly. SUPEE 8788 is not compatible with 1533

Comment: I customized the patch files to work for all Magento versions after installing all previous patches: https://magentohosting.pro/files/MageHost.pro_fixed_SUPEE-8788_v2.zip

Comment: @JonHolland Because, well, it's Magento.

Comment: This answer is not relevant anymore. Magento updated this patch (8788) to include patch 1533. So avoid this issue by using Patch 8788 v2.

Comment: @JeroenVermeulenBVBA Your updated v2 patch doesn't address the issue of "Product Image not displaying/uploading in the admin product edit form after 8788 applied". Can you suggest something for that ?

Comment: @VickyDev I don't see that problem on the shops we patched. It may only exist in certain cases.

Answer (score 24):

If you get

`Call to undefined function hash_equals() error`

even if your patch was successful then it may mean that you have copied functions.php in `app/code/local/Mage/Core`.

You will have to insert that function there too because that file overwrites the core one.

So insert in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/functions.php` at the end:

```
if (!function_exists('hash_equals')) {
    /**
     * Compares two strings using the same time whether they're equal or not.
     * A difference in length will leak
     *
     * @param string $known_string
     * @param string $user_string
     * @return boolean Returns true when the two strings are equal, false otherwise.
     */
    function hash_equals($known_string, $user_string)
    {
        $result = 0;

        if (!is_string($known_string)) {
            trigger_error("hash_equals(): Expected known_string to be a string", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        if (!is_string($user_string)) {
            trigger_error("hash_equals(): Expected user_string to be a string", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        if (strlen($known_string) != strlen($user_string)) {
            return false;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($known_string); $i++) {
            $result |= (ord($known_string[$i]) ^ ord($user_string[$i]));
        }

        return 0 === $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Offhand I know that Fishpig requires you to do this. So if you have that installed this will be an issue for you.

Comment: Note: I was confused and it is MWI that asks you to override functions.php, not Fishpig http://www.mwi-plugin.com/documentation/installation/

Answer (score 18):

In `PATCH_SUPEE-8788_EE_1.14.2.0_v1-2016-10-10-02-27-03.sh`, a file `test_oauth.php` is created in the Magento root directory. You will want to delete this one (or at least not deploy it to production) because it could expose a complete exception stack trace to the person calling the URL https://thedomain.tld/test_oauth.php.

Comment: Nice catch, Matthias! Would be somewhat bad form to deploy 17 APPSEC patches and open up another vector at the same time. Did you report this to Magento yet?

Comment: I did open a ticket about this with Magento Support, as I'm sure others have at this point. Haven't heard back about a v2 version of the patch, but they should be aware of the issue.

Comment: There will be a v2, should be published very soon. Yes, I reported it when I posted here.

Comment: Looks like that is fixed now

Answer (score 18):

**THIS APPLIES FOR 1.7 MAGENTO VERSIONS**

---

If you are running 1.7.0.2 version 2 of SUPEE 8788 **will fail** on line 372 trying to apply changes to `Curl.php`:

```
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 372.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client
```

The instructions say that we should **revert SUPEE-1533** and **install SUPEE-3941**

**PROBLEM:** SUPEE-3941 is only available for Magento CE 1.8-1.9. You can try applying it for 1.7, and it will apply. I think <del>patch developers</del> Magento should either release a version 3 of SUPEE-8788 for those running magento's below 1.8 or create an additional SUPEE-3941 patch that is designed for version below 1.8.

B.t.w. version 1 of SUPEE-8788 **did not** have the `Curl.php` error on 1.7.0.2 (I tested it on many installs)

Tip: if you are facing .swf errors at the end, make sure you Compress your patch, upload to the server and decompress there.SWF error will be gone.

**UPDATE:**

Magento said that basically it is okay to install the SUPEE-3941 patch on a Magento 1.7.0.2 version to avoid errors on applying SUPEE-8788

Comment: We've been given up

Comment: @kavoir.com you also get same CURL.PHP error when installing on 1.7.0.2 ??

Comment: Same issue here install 8788 V2  on 1.7.0.2 , although interesting we get the same curl.php error  on our newer 1.9.2.1 version sites which do not have SUPEE-3941 available . reverting 1533 doesn't help that problem either

Comment: @JonHolland I wrote to magento team... I hope they will respond

Comment: @Icon did you end up hearing back?

Comment: Here you go https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788-V2-SUPEE-3941-is-it-safe-to-apply-to-1-7-0-2/td-p/50970/page/2

Comment: I got  a reply from magento community leader, basically it is okey to install 3941 patch on 1.7.0.2 version..

Comment: Confirmed on CE 1.7.0.2! Apply SUPEE-3941 before 8788 v2. Also revert SUPEE-1533 to start with to prevent `DashboardController.php FAILED at 91`, see http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/141036/3326

Comment: @Icon Any confirmation on applying SUPEE-3941 on CE 1.6.2.0 ? I tried to apply the 3941 on CE 1.6.2.0 and it failed.

Answer (score 15):

Original **DashboardController.php** (1.7.0.2- Not pached, Fresh from magento)

```
  if ($params = unserialize(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)))) {
```

1533 Patched  DashboardController.php contains the following change

```
 if ($newHash == $gaHash) {
            $params = json_decode(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)), true);
            if ($params) {
```

8788 patch makes the following change in DashboardController.php

```
 if (hash_equals($newHash, $gaHash)) {
            if ($params = unserialize(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)))) {
```

As you can see 8788 has a modified change compared to 1533, I am NOT sure whther its ideal to modify the file as mpchadwick suggests, by manually replacing 8788 change with 1533 after installing 8788. Basically removing 8788 change.

Any suggestions?

Comment: IMO The desired end result is a mix of the two. It should be json_decode, but it should use the hash_equals rather than ==. This prevents a timing attacking (which would be extremely hard to exploit).

Comment: Agree with @Peter. If you use Git, revert the commit for SUPEE-1533, apply the new patch, commit, then revert the reverting commit again. The conflict in `DashboardController.php` should be solved automatically then.

Comment: Could you please provide a piece of code for DashboardController.php that we should replace after installing 8788? I am not exactly sure what to edit, like I have mentioned above, 1533 and 8788 patchd lines look different. Could you please provide how a Manually modified version should look like?

Comment: Is this how 8788 code should look like after manual modification with 1533 update? if (hash_equals($newHash, $gaHash)) {
            if ($params = json_decode(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)))) {

Comment: Note regarding reverting commits two times: you may be able to use `git revert -n 123456ab` and `git cherry-pick -n 123456ab` to temporarily undo SUPEE-1533 without creating extra commits for it.

Comment: I am doing old way, I simply replaced DashboardController.php with original 1.7 (Fresh file) and installed 8788 patch... Now I am trying to add SUPEE 1533 changes to that file, during which I am lost. I am asking if anyone could provide a portion of a manully edited code after 8788 update.

Answer (score 14):

Half tempted to flag this post as primarily opinion based or without a clear answer ;)

Form keys have been added to a couple of controllers, the number varies depending on your magento version.

If you experience trouble

- Removing an item from the wishlist
- Deleting a customers address from the store view
- Updating a quote item in your basket

You'll need to check your themes `.phtml` file and make sure you're `POST`ing over the form key parameter so it will pass the check in the controller actions like:

```
class Mage_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action

     public function updatePostAction()
     {
+        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
+            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
+            return;
+        }
+
```

These problems tripped a lot of people up in previous patches, custom frontend themes with overridden templates are easily missed when applying the patches.

Form keys are often added to the `.phtml` template containing the form as an extra `input` like

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Comment: Is there a full list of forms that this affect? So I can test and get them ALL fixed once and for all. Don't want secretly stupid dysfunctions such as this to annoy customers or drive down conversion rate.

Comment: If a SUPEE 8788 installs perfectly on 1.7 and it does make changes in (app/design/frontend/base/default/template.....). But despite the change website frontend wishlist,  add remove buttons all work perfectly. Do we still need to manually patch theme files? Or, as long patch doesn't break anything on frontend we can leave as-is?

Answer (score 11):

**I met the same problem in swf in 1.9.2.4.**

> Fox Fixed - Please follow below steps.
>
> Step 1. Download security patch 8788 SSH file to this Link :- https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/magento/
>
> Step 2. After download security patch 8788 SSH file Please put into one folder and make same folder Zip file.
>
> Step 3. Please upload Zip folder to root magento folder and Unzip through SSH Putty.
>
> Step 4. Run the patch :-
>   $ bash PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2016-10-11-07-03-46.sh

*Note : he patch file contains entire binary files in text format.That's why when you upload security patch 8788 SSH file without zip file, the same file will be corrupt. *

Answer (score 10):

After appyling SUPEE-8788 I was no longer able to load "Import" profiles using Unirgy_RapidFlow 2.0.0.18, getting a 500 error (nothing in Apache or HTTPD logs).

I am still in the process of debugging and working with Unirgy to resolve, but it appears that the uploader block is causing the issue (`Unirgy_RapidFlow_Block_Adminhtml_Profile_Edit_Tab_Upload`).

The patch introduced several changes to `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content`, the parent.

In addition to uRapidFlow, other 3rd party modules that allow for file upload could break as a result of SUPEE-8788.

Comment: have you find a solution for this already? I fixed it by replacing
$this->getUploader()->getConfig() with $this->getUploader()->getUploaderConfig() in Unirgy_RapidFlow_Block_Adminhtml_Profile_Edit_Tab_Upload

Comment: Good to now. Unirgy also seems to have fixed it in 2.0.0.23. https://secure.unirgy.com/release-notes.php?m=1#RapidFlow I'm working with a client to purchase additional upgrades and haven't been able to validate.

Comment: run this on your docroot to find which other files needs to be fixed: grep -r 'getUploader()->getConfig()' ./

Answer (score 8):

I got the following message when executing the patch script:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 4753
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
|index 6d0607e..5757be3 100644
|--- downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
|+++ downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
```

I think this is because I renamed the "downloader" folder, following recommendations from https://www.magereport.com.

I temporarily renamed the folder to "downloader", applied the patch correctly and then renamed it with its secret name.

Answer (score 8):

Patch on 1.9.0.0 fails too (probably 1.8.0.0 until 1.9.0.1 affected) because of SUPEE-3941.
3941 patches downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php and now the 8788 fails.

```
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 378.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
```

Workaround for 1.9.0.1 below. Changes are too thorough, maybe need to adjust the 8788 patch itself.

edit:
Edit the patch, search for Curl.php and replace

```
diff --git downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
index c55f88d..31f9f77 100644
--- downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
+++ downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
@@ -378,8 +378,8 @@ implements Mage_HTTP_IClient
         }

         $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
-        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
-        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
+        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
+        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 'TLSv1');

         // force method to POST if secured
         if ($isAuthorizationRequired) {
diff --git js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
```

with

```
diff --git downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
index c55f88d..31f9f77 100644
--- downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
+++ downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
@@ -378,8 +378,8 @@ implements Mage_HTTP_IClient
         $uriModified = $this->getSecureRequest($uri, $isAuthorizationRequired);
         $this->_ch = curl_init();
         $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_URL, $uriModified);
-        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
-        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
+        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
+        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 'TLSv1');
         $this->getCurlMethodSettings($method, $params, $isAuthorizationRequired);

         if(count($this->_headers)) {
diff --git js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
```

Comment: I customized the patch files to work for all Magento versions after installing all previous patches: https://magentohosting.pro/files/MageHost.pro_fixed_SUPEE-8788_v2.zip

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I'm getting

```
Hunk #1 FAILED at 373.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php.rej
patching file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css
```

Comment: Getting the exact same error io an install. Would love to know if you figured anything out.

Comment: Nope, still waiting for someone else to figure this out

Comment: See http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/73957/9276. If your Curl.php file has this fix, then undo that change (revert the line to CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST / 'TLSv1'), apply the patch, and the redo the change.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. Was just coming back here to post the same info. You beat me to it! That's what I get for going to sleep. :)

Comment: Had the same issue, this resolved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Looks like Magento will be releasing **updated version** of the SUPEE 8788, to fix the  SUPEE 1533 compatibility. I am not sure if its good idea to apply manually fixes right now. Manual changes may compromise future patch updates. Would like to hear your thoughts.

**It has been confirmed by Magento Community Manager.** 
As oct 13, 3pm EST.. all patches for versions below 1.9 are deleted from download list
https://www.magentocommerce.com/download?_ga=1.236497153.1889606568.1445610645
See post:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788-AND-SUPEE-1533-Incompatible-Hunk-error/m-p/50514/highlight/false#M1805

Comment: **If** the updated patch has exactly the same result than our manual fixes, and I hope that's the case, then I don't see a problem. The updated patch won't be necessary and future patches won't see a difference.

Comment: @fschmengler pretty similar to the PHP 5.5 incompatibility for SUPEE-7405 IMO. The patch will reflect the manual fix.

Comment: @fschmengler To my knowledge magento will release exactly the same patch again with fixes. I gues its best to remove old patch (self modified) and install new (probably release next day. By tomorrow we should have update. Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm not doubting the value of this contribution, but sticking to Q&A style, this answer doesn't seems like an answer to me, more of an update that @fschmengler could add to his original question (or you can add it to the Community Wiki answer).

Answer (score 8):

We are getting reports of the following new issues that I don't see in other posts:

- Exception in the new releases in some cases -  addCrumbs() method call (in case getStoreConfig(web/default/show_cms_breadcrumbs) is undefined). Should not affect the patch, only the 1.9.3/1.14.3 release

<strike>'Exception' with message 'Unsupported data type N' in /lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php in 1.9.1.0 and possibly earlier versions when patch is applied.</strike> resolved in patch version 2.

There are currently no known easy workarounds for those issues. We are working to resolve them in a new patch version.

Comment: Possible fix for the Unsupported data type N error https://gist.github.com/balloz/ceaf5feb5ac66caaa82342441d32aa88

Comment: Any idea how to overcome Curl.php error when installing SUPEE 8788 on 1.6 and 1.7 versions?

Answer (score 8):

Uploader breaks when you upload the same file for samples and links at the same time for downloadable products. Note that this only happens if you use the same file in both areas. (It used to work correctly before the patch.)

To reproduce, edit a downloadable product and click on the *Downloadable Information* tab:

1. Open the *Samples* row of the accordion and browse for a sample file.
2. On the *Links* row of the accordion, browse for a download link
3. Click *Upload Files* from within the Links section.

The uploader uploads the sample file instead of the downloadable link file, and the file you browsed for in the downloadable link section disappears.

I was able to reproduce this on a vanilla, patched 1.7.0.2 CE install.

Comment: Turns out this is the behavior of the underlying JS lib used for uploading: https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js/issues/76

Answer (score 6):

### Editing Patch File

If anyone has to edit the patch file, you should not being do it in an editor as this will break the binary files encapsulated in the patch.

If you have a command line handy ie. linux/*unix try using `sed` utility to remove specific lines.

Props to @fooman for the tip. See his [original gist](https://gist.github.com/fooman/b8f4ddbeadf4adebffd911f3411e3d70)

Example `sed -ie '101,111d' PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2016-10-11-06-36-18.sh`

This will delete line 101 to 111 inclusively.

### Form Submission Issues.

If you are seeing the above mentioned for issue you can also you:

```
<?= $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

For more information refer to this post [What is getBlockHtml('formkey')?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43962/what-is-getblockhtmlformkey)

Comment: Be careful with `<?=` it is not enabled on every php configuration

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism you're correct. Although `<?=` is enabled by default in most php.ini configurations some hosts do choose to disabled it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I did encounter other issue when login, it will always return this:

I found that is because on class Enterprise_Pci_Model_Observer line 165,

Instead of:

```
if (!Mage::helper('core')->getEncryptor()->validateHashByVersion($password, $model->getPassword())) {
```

This will fix:

```
if (!Mage::helper('core')->getEncryptor()->validateHashByVersion($password, $model->getPasswordHash())) {
```

Since I don't like changing core (even move to local), it's best if Magento fix this or clarify this. At the moment mine is creating new extensions to extend this and create function for getPassword() (since I want to make sure all devs use Developer mode on).

Comment: Having now applied the V2 of the patch, I am encountering the same issue patching EE1.12. It looks like this file has changed at some point between 1.12 and 1.14 but not as part of the patches

Comment: Raised this with Magento and they supplied a further patch to address the issue. The change is identical to that above.

Answer (score 5):

**CE 1.6.2.0 & SUPEE-3941**

To apply security patch SUPEE-8788 (Version 2), (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html#apply-8788-new) it is suggested to apply SUPEE-3941 first.

However, on the patch download page, there is no SUPEE-3941 patch for CE 1.6.2.0. The patch is available only for CE 1.8 and 1.9.

As mentioned in this thread, it seems to be okay to apply the available SUPEE-3941 patch (for CE 1.8 & 1.9) on CE 1.7.

Is it also okay to apply SUPEE-3941 (for CE 1.8 & 1.9) on CE 1.6.2.0? I tried applying it on CE 1.6.2.0 and got the following error:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 489 (offset 3 lines).
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Backup.php
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 64.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 205 with fuzz 2 (offset -44 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 382 (offset -53 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Install.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 90.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 333 with fuzz 1 (offset 17 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 363 (offset 17 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php
Hunk #4 FAILED at 268.
Hunk #5 FAILED at 290.
Hunk #6 succeeded at 369 with fuzz 2.
Hunk #7 FAILED at 377.
Hunk #9 FAILED at 428.
4 out of 10 hunks FAILED
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 71 with fuzz 2 (offset -11 lines).
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Singleconfig.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 100 (offset -36 lines).
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Validator.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 418 (offset -41 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 431 (offset -41 lines).
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
checking file downloader/template/settings.phtml
```

Answer (score 5):

A little late but we found a problem in patch SUPEE-8788 V2 which *at least* applies to the patch files for Magento 1.7.0.2 and 1.7.0.1. Probably this also applies to all prior versions for which a patch version exists. Magento version from 1.8 on are not affected as the patch doesn't change templates for those.

### In detail

The patch is missing a formkey for file 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml`

Without it login doesn't work on onepage checkout (it just doesn't work without error).

### Fix

A formkey has to be inserted like in following patch:

```
diff --git a/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml b/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
index 9d15a577b..18483a3c5 100644
--- a/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
+++ b/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
@@ -71,6 +71,7 @@
         <h3><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></h3>
         <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
         <form id="login-form" action="<?php echo $this->getPostAction() ?>" method="post">
+        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
         <fieldset>
             <h4><?php echo $this->__('Already registered?') ?></h4>
             <p><?php echo $this->__('Please log in below:') ?></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

For 1533 Patched site just replace below line from  PATCH_SUPEE-8788*****.sh :

```
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
index 09ffc4c..367bf8e 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
@@ -91,7 +91,7 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Actio
         $gaHash = $this->getRequest()->getParam('h');
         if ($gaData && $gaHash) {
             $newHash = Mage::helper('adminhtml/dashboard_data')->getChartDataHash($gaData);
-            if ($newHash == $gaHash) {
+            if (hash_equals($newHash, $gaHash)) {
                 if ($params = unserialize(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)))) {
                     $response = $httpClient->setUri(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph::API_URL)
                             ->setParameterGet($params)
```

by:

```
diff --git a/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php b/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
index ab2d654..367bf8e 100644
--- a/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
@@ -91,9 +91,8 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Actio
         $gaHash = $this->getRequest()->getParam('h');
         if ($gaData && $gaHash) {
             $newHash = Mage::helper('adminhtml/dashboard_data')->getChartDataHash($gaData);
-            if ($newHash == $gaHash) {
-                $params = json_decode(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)), true);
-                if ($params) {
+            if (hash_equals($newHash, $gaHash)) {
+                if ($params = unserialize(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)))) {
                     $response = $httpClient->setUri(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph::API_URL)
                             ->setParameterGet($params)
                             ->setConfig(array('timeout' => 5))
diff --git a/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php b/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
index da1b14a..b6d72c0 100644
--- a/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
@@ -444,7 +444,7 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboar
             }
             return self::API_URL . '?' . implode('&', $p);
         } else {
-            $gaData = urlencode(base64_encode(json_encode($params)));
+            $gaData = urlencode(base64_encode(serialize($params)));
             $gaHash = Mage::helper('adminhtml/dashboard_data')->getChartDataHash($gaData);
             $params = array('ga' => $gaData, 'h' => $gaHash);
             return $this->getUrl('*/*/tunnel', array('_query' => $params));
```

Basically it just reverted the 1533 and left 8788 along.

Comment: As I understand the 8788 overrides changes in DashboardController.php, and original 1533 changes will be eliminated?

Comment: Yes the purpose of 1533  replacing  serialize() by json_encode() was to reduce the chance of attack pass  ($newHash == $gaHash). While 8788 adds hash_equals() for the same purpose

Comment: Great, I was thinkin of doing slightly other way, on my test site I uploaded clean DashboardController.php (stock magento file) and installed SUPEE 8788. However, I read on this forum and a gentleman mentioned to manually reintroduce supee 1533 changes to Supee 8988 modified file. What you think about my method?

Comment: Icon, look at my diff above, in your way you need to change back the line updated by SUPEE 1533 in 'app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php' as well if you already have SUPEE 1533 patched. Otherwise Graph.php will  fire out json format params and you wont be able to decode it by unserialize()

Answer (score 4):

Authorize.net capture is broken after applying the patch. Authorizing works good, but when capturing the payment to invoice it gives **"Gateway error: Credit card number is required"**. Payment log file shows `x_type` param passes value `auth_capture` now, but before the patch it used to pass `prior_auth_capture` which worked well. Anyone experiencing this issue?

UPDATE: Fix for this issue - [Authorize.net not capturing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141285/authorize-net-not-capturing)

Answer (score 4):

I have patched a copy of Magento 1.9.2.4 using SSH with SUPEE-8788
I have patched another copy of Magento 1.9.2.4 using ftp with SUPEE-8788
I have patched a copy of magento 1.9.1.0 using SSH with SUPEE-8788
I have used a fresh copy of magento 1.9.3.1

In all these magento web sites with SUPEE-8788 i experience the same problem (maybe a bug of the patch)

Using downloadable products and going in **Downloadable information->Samples** when i try to **Add a new row** (one or more) by clicking on the "X" i'm not able anymore to remove the row[image]

I'm not so expert in Magento i'm trying to find a solution. If i will find i will post, if anyone of you have some solution it will be very very usefull for me

**UPDATE**: using Chrome inspector i saw this error:[image]

*******  **I FOUND THE SOLUTION**   *******

I spent 2 days and i hope this can help someone else, this is a bug in SUPEE-8788

Open samples.phtml inside `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable`

Find the function

> ```
> remove : function(event){
>     var element = $(Event.findElement(event, 'tr'));
>     alertAlreadyDisplayed = false;
>     if(element){
>         element.down('input[type="hidden"].__delete__').value = '1';
>         element.down('div.flex').remove();
>         element.addClassName('no-display');
>         element.addClassName('ignore-validate');
>         element.hide();
>     }
> },
> ```

and replace it with

> ```
> remove : function(event){
>     var element = $(Event.findElement(event, 'tr'));
>     alertAlreadyDisplayed = false;
>     if(element){
>         element.down('input[type="hidden"].__delete__').value = '1';
>         Element.select(element, 'div.flex').each(function(elm){
>             elm.remove();
>         });
>         element.addClassName('no-display');
>         element.addClassName('ignore-validate');
>         element.hide();
>     }
> },
> ```

This will solve the BUG

Answer (score 3):

Applied PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.1_v1-2016-10-11-07-00-43 on test copy of site running 1.9.2.1 and it has broken the checkout. Revert the patch and the checkout works normally again.

When submitting the order it takes you back to the cart instead of checkout success. Think I'll be waiting for the .1 version before trying again.

Comment: sounds like an exception is thrown while the order is saved, have you checked your logs?

Comment: Looks that way...

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Core_Helper_UnserializeArray' not found in .../public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: @AdamLavery Go to Var/cache and delete the cache folder. I get that error when I revert the paches back to original. Its a cache thing.

Comment: New patch should be out soon. This is a huge patch update to expect no errors... Yeah... fingers crossed.

Comment: This is the test site so I don't have caching enabled.

Comment: This is likely because you're missing `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php` This was added in SUPEE-6788, which you may not have installed. It looks like SUPEE-8788 has an undocumented dependency on SUPEE-6788.

Answer (score 3):

New email in the early hours from Magento states that they will be producing new patch versions to deal with the SUPEE-1533 and SUPEE-3941 compatibility issues.  So maybe just hold your horses for a bit.

> ENTERPRISE EDITION 1.14.3, COMMUNITY EDITION 1.9.3, AND SUPEE-8788 
>   Enterprise Edition 1.14.3 and Community Edition 1.9.3 deliver over 120 quality improvements, as well as support for PHP 5.6. They also resolve critical security issues, including: ...
>
> ...The SUPEE-8788 patch addresses these security issues in earlier Magento versions. Unfortunately, we have discovered that the SUPEE-8788 patches for Community Edition 1.8 and earlier releases and Enterprise Edition 1.13 and earlier releases fail if a store has previously applied SUPEE-1533 or SUPEE-3941 security patches. We are working to correct this issue and will provide new patches in the next one to three days. Until then, we are removing these versions of the SUPEE-8788 patch from distribution...

However I am concerned that my active Magento versions fall between the CE 1.9.3 that they say works  and the new versions coming soon for V1.8 and below. I have contacted them so will wait and see what they say.

Comment: Not really an "answer" but useful info hopefully.

Comment: Hi Jon, you could also edit @fschmengler's original question and add this on the bottom as an **UPDATE**. I think he would be fine with that and approve that edit.

Comment: Good idea but someone has already added something :)

Answer (score 3):

I am not a big fan of patching. Personally I remove all Magento files from their directories then upload the new version (using a shell script). All the files installed over the years like modules or themes are still there. For database I make a comparison between fresh installed versions. One way is creating or removing the columns/tables into the database, the other way is installing again Magento just changing /app/etc/local.xml file name. I prefer the first one.

If you do not change the database structure to version 1.9.3.0 you will get some errors or you cannot load admin area. If anyone is interested in some comparisons for Magento directories and databases between Magento CE 1.9.2.4 and 1.9.3.0 just download the file from here:

[Magento Comparison: versions 1.9.2.4 - 1.9.3.0](https://we.tl/TxAKMTsapX)

There are two html files with very nice visual results.

I updated 4 stores today using my method instead of patching. All are running without any issues.

Comment: That's nice if you are on the most recent version and there is a new release for the patch, as it was the case with 1.9.2.2, 1.9.2.3 and 1.9.2.4 - however for this patch there was no new release 1.9.2.5. Version 1.9.3.0 contains a bunch of additional changes that are not security related.

Comment: With my method I got two in one, security updates and new features. The only problem is you have to understand what is happening into the file system and database between releases. It is not a big deal when you know what you are doing. And you have a better control. I am doing this method since 1.7 version.

Answer (score 3):

Not having any luck on most installs of Magento CE (6 total). Different versions: 1.9.1, 1.9.0.1, 1.8.1.

I've downloaded the correct corresponding 8788 patch. I've made sure to revert 1533 when applicable.

I get the following key notable outputs that are questionable:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
```

...

```
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 372.
```

...
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
    Hunk #1 succeeded at 373 (offset -19 lines).
...

```
can't find file to patch at input line 5810
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Parser.php lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|index 423902a..2c01684 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Parser.ph
```

Same as above for:
lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
And says those hunks ignored.

note: There is nothing in my Unserialized/Reader dir. Completely empty.
note: the Curl.php is in downloader dir. Not renamed. 
It finishes, but I don't see the SWF files removed. I don't see the patch applied in the list of applied.patches.list

Makes no sense.

Comment: Ok.. figured it all out. Definitely need to work thru ALL old patches, in order. I had a couple older patches that hadn't been applied. Once I pulled down those, and applied on up the line, things started patching sucessfully. However, I did find that whenever I got a hunk error on a file for ANY patch, I had to go into the patch and find what it was trying to replace and manually do it in my magento install. THEN remove those "diff" lines from the patch and rerun. Essentially any time you see a hunk error, go into the patch and see what it's attempting to +/- from it, and then do it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I've patched about 10 websites today, and every site where the SUPEE-8788 patch failed had the **SUPEE-6788 MISSING**.

This resulted in (example) the following error:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 5810
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Parser.php lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|index 423902a..2c01684 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
```

After installing SUPEE-6788 the SUPEE-8788 patched correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting `Hunk #1 failed` at xxx Error , This is what i did

I got `Hunk #1 failed at 373`. Error !! after the line

> checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php

So i checked the `Curl.php` file and found that i had modified the file before (commented one line ). I restored the original file and ran the patch again. Then the patch was successful. ;) .

Then i checked :

**`/app/etc/applied.patches.list` & everything seems good**