# SUPEE-8788 1.7.0.2 - Error Applying Patch

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, supee-8788

**Background**
Mage 1.7.0.2.
Fully-patched except USPS patches (see note below).
No manual edits have been made to install files failing patch.

**Problem Summary**
2 Installs: Fails with message ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

**Problem Detail**
2 specific failures in the report:

1. Both installs: "patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
   Hunk #1 FAILED at 91."
2. One install: "patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
   Hunk #1 FAILED at 38."

**Research Done**

1. Searched through all 1.x patches for those two files. Error 1 (DashboardController.php) is changed in one other patch: SUPEE-1533, which is applied to both installs. Error 2 file (customer/form/login.phtml) isn't found in any patches)

   2. Specifically looked at the un-applied USPS patches; neither of the files that won't patch are touched by those patches

Comment: Does he answer here help you? 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140558/17176

Answer (score 3):

```
If you've previously applied SUPEE-1533 then the patch will fail on
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php.
```

**I solved this by...**

```
1.Manually revert the changes introduced to that file by SUPEE-1533
2.Apply SUPEE-8788
3.Manually reintroduce the changes introduced to that file by SUPEE-1533
```

Removing the change from the SUPEE-8788 is dangerous because the patch file contains binary data and saving it in an editor can cause issues (another gotcha).

Answer (score 0):

My DashboardController looks a little different than the patch is trying to fix. If I correct the controller the patch works.

Lines in my controller:

```
$params = json_decode(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)), true);
    if ($params) {
```

Line the patch is looking for:

```
if ($params = unserialize(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)))) {
```