# SUPEE-8788 and SUPEE 1533 (How to approach?)

Tags: magento-1, security, patches, supee-8788

As many are aware if you have SUPEE 1533 installed you cannot install SUPEE 8788.

I figured that Reversing/uninstalling Supee 1533, we can install SUPEE 8788. But, then we cannot install SUPEE 1533 back. How to approach ? Should we forget about installing SUPEE 1533 after we install SUPEE 8788? Or should we manually modify the

Original **DashboardController.php** (1.7.0.2- Not pached, Fresh from magento)

```
  if ($params = unserialize(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)))) {
```

1533 Patched  DashboardController.php contains the following change

```
 if ($newHash == $gaHash) {
            $params = json_decode(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)), true);
            if ($params) {
```

8788 patch makes the following change in DashboardController.php

```
 if (hash_equals($newHash, $gaHash)) {
            if ($params = unserialize(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)))) {
```

As you can see 8788 has a modified change compared to 1533 so as other suggest its not ideal to manually replace 8788 change with 1533 after installing 8788.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Beware if you applied SUPEE-1533 : you may have to manually revert 1533, apply 8788, manually reapply 1533

Comment: For anyone having problems with the .swf updates of the patch, I simply removed lines 5951-9818 from the patch and manually removed the .swf files from /skin/adminhtml/default/default/media - since that's all the patch was doing anyway.

Comment: Attention, the line numbers will vary dependent on your Magento version. So review the change before removing lines blindly, it should only remove the diff for *.swf files

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll want to follow this questions: [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

You'll find a solution/approach there.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what they mean by 1. Manually revert the changes introduced to that file by SUPEE-1533
2. Apply SUPEE-8788
3. Manually reintroduce the changes introduced to that file by SUPEE-153

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me on `1.7.0.2`.

Edit the patch file `PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2016-10-11-06-36-18.sh` and remove everything from line `503 to line 516`. The key here is that the line numbering remain untouched. This means that line 503 to 516 must still be in the file but will be empty.

**Failure to do so will cause the patch script to throw you an error.**

Don't forget to make the change you removed from the patch manually in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php`.

[Example gist](https://gist.github.com/sergeifilippov/5ca2b2a77fe706740853cb869bc0097a#file-patch_supee-8788_ce_1-7-0-2_v1-2016-10-11-06-36-18-sh-L503)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am confused about this issue, if we skip lines, basically 8788 will not edit DashbaordController.php file, wouldn't it leave the store vulnurable? I've posted above, there is  small change in the line between 1533 and 8788 patch. What do you think?

Comment: I've updated the comment with a link to a gist of the patch I used so you see exactly the lines I've removed.

Comment: @Icon I've adjusted the wording, but you **DEFINITELY SHOULD** make the changes to Magento as the patch would have. I only removed the section from my patch so the rest of the changes get done by the patch script.

Comment: Great, I am lookint at it right now. If we skip the DashboardControl.php update, dont you think it will leave the system vulnerable? Seems like 8788 replaced 1533 patch changes. Wherease what we are doing is keeping 1533 patch changes. What you think?

Comment: My original method was this: Upload 1.7.0.2 Original DashboardControl.php file and replace it with 1533 modified one. Install 8788 patch and forget about manually applying 1533 since 8788 already patches Fresh  1.7.0.2  Dashboardcontroller.php

Comment: I followed Icon's approach and it now installs without a problem. Once 8788 has been installed there is no need to apply 1533 back

Comment: Make sure to test ability to upload product images and cms content to be safe.

Comment: Could you show the lines that you are removing? Not all the patches have the correct line numbers from your solution.

Comment: Wait until version 2 of the patch released... mage developers found incopatibility in the present patch.