# SUPEE-8788 on OSX - illegal byte sequence

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-8788

When applying SUPEE-8788 on Magento 1.9.2.4 on OSX I get the following

```
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

Should I worry about the illegal byte sequence because it states it was applied successfully

Answer (score 3):

Try running it like

`LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=C ./PATCH_SUPEE-8788_EE_1.13.0.1_v1.sh`

This should force everything to work a bit nicer.

On OSX by default `$LANG` is defined like:

```
echo $LANG
en_GB.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running this in the command line before running the patch

```
export LANG=C
```

It should fix it, you may need to run these as well, I tried all 3 and it worked after the one above

```
export LL_CTYPE=C

export LL_ALL=C
```

Taken from this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287564/getting-sed-error-illegal-byte-sequence-in-bash

Comment: Does it have any negative effect on the application of the patch though? It still seems to work..

Answer (score 1):

The above suggested fixes didn't work for me so I installed GNU sed from homebrew via `brew install gnu-sed` and changed the line in patch file to read

> SED_BIN=`which gsed`