# Security Patch SUPEE-8788 failing at downloader/Maged/View.php (M1 v1.5.1.0)

Tags: magento-1, security, supee-6788

On magento v1.5.1.0 patch Supee 8788 fails at downloader/Maged/View.php

I downloaded a fresh install of Magento v1.5.1.0, copied the downloader file over and retried but still fails with the same error:

```
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 154.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/Maged/View.php.rej
```

Comment: How is this a duplicate? This is not an answer, but a statement on why it's not working. The answer below is fine, and correct.

Answer (score 5):

To fix this:

Download the latest version of Magento (currently v1.9.3.0) and replace the downloader/Maged/View.php file with the one from the latest release.

Then remove this function (around line: 156):

```
/**
   * Retrieve Session Form Key
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getFormKey()
  {
      return $this->controller()->getFormKey();
  }
```

Run the patch install again and the patch will be applied successfully.

Comment: This is a very nice way to solve these conflicts with Magento patches! And I can be applied not only in that case. Thank you for sharing.