# Magento 1.9.2.2 SUPEE-8788 v2 Hunk #1 FAILED

Tags: magento-1.9

I have attempted to apply the new Magento security patch Magento 1.9.2.2 SUPEE-8788 but it is failing on one file as follows:

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 947.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 1063.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php.rej
```

I had exactly the same problem with V1 of the patch but hoped the new one may resolve it.

We are using Magento 1.9.2.2 and already have patch SUPEE-7405 installed.

Can anyone help please?

Adam