# Authorize.net not capturing

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

I recently applied the latest security patches on the website which went successful. But after the patches, we found that we are not able to capture the funds now. We can authorize the payment, but when clicking on capture in Invoice it gives "Gateway error: Credit card is required". I cross-checked the log response with our earlier successful captures and found that `x_type` in the request was going as `prior_auth_capture` whereas now it's going as `auth_capture`. I think this is the reason of fail, how to send the request to capture as `prior_auth_capture`?

Any ideas what could be wrong. Note that we have not changed any config settings or anything, just applied last few patches that's it.

Comment: I encountered the same issue. Tracked it back to applying the security patch. In the Admin console it says "Order was placed using USD" instead of the usual x'd out CC information.  Adding notes to this to see if it helps resolve. Here is a similar thread on the Magento forums, but not sure if the solution mentioned is a good path: https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788-preventing-site-from-capturing-authorize-net-payment/td-p/50581

Comment: It looks like they have resolved this issue with a v2 of the patch. Here are the instructions on the patch site:

NOTE: if you have installed version 1 of the patch, it is recommended to do the following:
Revert SUPEE-8788 v1/
Revert SUPEE-1533 (if installed)
Install SUPEE-3941 (if not installed yet)
Install SUPEE-8788 v2
https://www.magentocommerce.com/download?_ga=1.115227200.699210376.1476757336

Going to try this out.

Comment: I already tried the solution mentioned in that thread without any luck. Thanks for the update on v2 of the patch, i installed v1. I will try out v2 and see if that resolves. Thank you very much coreyg!

Comment: I just tried the v1 revert and applied the v2 patch. This resolved the issue of  "Order was placed using USD" just showing instead of the CC info. I'm going to monitor for the next transaction to see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: Great. I am getting errors when applying patch 8788 v2, will update you once done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. The issue was with SUPEE-8788 v1 patch. After going through the steps to remove SUPEE-8788 v1 and install SUPEE-8788 v2 patch from [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download#download1934), the issue was finally resolved for all the NEW orders. For all the old orders, we had to manually settle them.

Steps to revert patch v1 and install v2:

```
NOTE: if you have installed version 1 of the patch, it is recommended to do the following:
Revert SUPEE-8788 v1/
Revert SUPEE-1533 (if installed)
Install SUPEE-3941 (if not installed yet)
Install SUPEE-8788 v2
```

Comment: Worked for me as well