# Where can i get patch SUPEE-3941 for installing SUPEE-8788 Magento 1.13.1 EE?

Tags: magento-enterprise, security, patches, ee-1.13, supee-8788

I tried to install SUPEE-8788 through this manual:
[image: applying SUPEE-8788]

But can't find patch SUPEE-3941. Where can i find it?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from the community download page:

1. https://www.magentocommerce.com/download
2. release archive
3. search for "SUPEE-3941"
4. download the version for Magento CE 1.8

The patch fixes issues in the Magento Connect downloader, which is the same for Magento Enterprise and Magento Community.

Comment: Yes, But it is in `.sh` format. .zip format is available anywhere? if yes pls share the link.

Answer (score 2):

It is here in the Magento download page under the Release Archive tab in the Magento Community Edition Patches - 1.x section (use CTRL/CMD + F to search 3941) :

https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

You can also use this repo from Brent Peterson to get any patch:

https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches