# Browse File button doesn't work (Only in AM Revolution Slider) after patch 8788

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, magento1.9.2.3, supee-8788

I have installed the SUPEE-8788 patch in Magento 1.9.2.3 CE. At the first time I have installed the v1 of the patch, now I have reverted it and I have installed the v2, but the issue persisting. When I try to change the image background in a slide of AM Revolution Slider, the "Browse File.." doesn't work, I can't change the image.
I'd try to clear Magento cache, browser cache, restart Apache2 but nothing.
I'd check the source of page and this file are not present:

- `/js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js`
- `/js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js`
- `/js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js`

Someone has an idea how I can solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

Comment: Hi Matteo, welcome to Magento SE! There's a lot of people on this site that know Magento, but they probably don't know anything about the AM Revolution Slider. So it would be best to contact the developer(s) of that module directly. The SUPEE-8788 patch is removing the image upload through Adobe Flash. My first guess would be that this module is depending on that. So their development team should update the AM Revolution Slider to no use the Flash uploader. Please contact them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you've deleted all the .swf files from `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/`. I had the same problem and removing them files fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I have already watched this, but the "media" folder doesn't exist in my /skin/adminhtml/default/default folder then the .swf it's already deleted.

Comment: You need to bare in mind that Magento have removed the .swf upload functionality. If the extension you're using is extending this functionality, it may no longer work. Your may need updating to reflect the Magento upload changes.