# Magento 1.9.2.1 Patch 8788

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-8788

in my magento 1.9.2.1 I insert the patch 8788 but i if I check my web site with MageReport.com the patch seems not fixed.

when i insert the patch the response is 
"Patch was applied/reverted successfully."

The patch is applied or not?

Comment: Please see also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141804/8788-v2-issues-and-questions/142225#142225

Answer (score 0):

check the following file app/etc/applied.patches.list. If it has SUPEE-8788 in it Ref: https://screencloud.net/v/5z45, then you can be sure that the patch has been successfuly applied in your magento instance