# Disallowed file format in Magento 1.9.2.2 after patch upload

Tags: magento-1.9, error, products, image, product-images

I installed **patch 8788** on my Magento shop, but now i get the error "Disalollowed file format." (I think they mean "Disallowed file format.") when i want to upload an image in at my products.

**How is this possible and how to solve it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SUPEE-8788 patch introduced maximum image dimensions in the configuration.

You get that error (indeed mispelled) from `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`:

```
public function validateUploadFile($filePath) {
    $maxDimension = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION);
    $imageInfo = getimagesize($filePath);
    if (!$imageInfo) {
        Mage::throwException($this->__('Disallowed file type.'));
    }

    if ($imageInfo[0] > $maxDimension || $imageInfo[1] > $maxDimension) {
        Mage::throwException($this->__('Disalollowed file format.'));
    }

    $_processor = new Varien_Image($filePath);
    return $_processor->getMimeType() !== null;
}
```

By default, the maximum image dimensions is 5000px so I reckon your image upload is bigger than this.

You can change the configuration under **System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image > Maximum resolution for upload image**

Comment: @KeesJanssen feel free to mark your question as accepted so it will benefit for the community ;)

Answer (score 2):

Under System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image 

I had to change *Maximum resolution for upload image* to 1200px. 
Then on Product > Images I got *Maximum width and height dimension for upload image is 1200*. Now I was able to add images. For me looks like a bug.