# Error in applying SUPEE-8788 in EE 1.13.1.0 - malformed patch at line 6139

Tags: magento-1, patches, supee-8788, ee-1.13.1.0

My Magento version is 1.13.1.0 and had SUPEE-1533 installed.

As per Magento guidelines I have reverted this patch and then applied SUPEE-3941 (previously not applied). These step went successfully. Now when I tried to apply `PATCH_SUPEE-8788_EE_1.13.1.0_v2-2016-10-14-11-52-21.sh` throwing below error output -

```
$ ./PATCH_SUPEE-8788_EE_1.13.1.0_v2-2016-10-14-11-52-21.sh`
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
/usr/bin/patch:  malformed patch at line 6139:
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
```

I have downloaded patch file directly from Magento server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

Comment: @AnandSingh Did you find the solution for this?