# PATCH_SUPEE-8788 on Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: patches, ce-1.9.2.2, supee-8788, supee-8788v2

I can't apply patch PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.2_v2-2016-10-14-09-41-22.sh

Here is a what I got

```
            PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.2_v2-2016-10-14-09-41-22.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.2_v2-2016-10-14-09-41-22.sh: 127: not found
            PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.2_v2-2016-10-14-09-41-22.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.2_v2-2016-10-14-09-41-22.sh: 127: not found
            PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.2_v2-2016-10-14-09-41-22.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.2_v2-2016-10-14-09-41-22.sh: 0: not found
            Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
            -e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
            Hunk #1 succeeded at 372 (offset -19 lines).
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design/Images.php
            checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
            checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
            checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
            checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
            checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
            checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml
            checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml
            checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
            checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
            checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
            checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design.phtml
            checking file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
            checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
            Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored
            checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
            checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
            checking file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
            checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
            checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
            checking file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
            checking file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
            checking file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
            checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
            checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
            checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
            checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
            checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
            checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
            checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
            Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
            Apply anyway? [n]
            Skipping patch.
            1 out of 1 hunk ignored
            checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css
```

( [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems) does not help because there is nothing about errors that I got "127: not found" and "patch detected in Mage_Media.csv" )

Answer (score 1):

Solved

First, to get rid of

```
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!
```

I use [this](https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788-fails-on-SWF-files/td-p/50421) solution: just need to zip patch and unzip it on server

Then

```
 checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
 Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
```

I remove Mage_Media.csv and upload new one from magento installation (despite the fact that file was the same)