# Applying PATCH 8788 fails

Tags: supee-8788v2

I have trouble getting the 8788 into place.

The Magento is a 1.9.2.4. The Error Message is:

```
./PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh
    Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
    -e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
    Hunk #1 FAILED at 91.
    1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design/Images.php
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
    checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
    checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
    checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
    checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
    checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml
    checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml
    checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
    checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
    checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
    checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design.phtml
    checking file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
    checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
    checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
    checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
    The next patch would create the file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    The next patch would create the file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    checking file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
    The next patch would create the file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js,
    which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
    Apply anyway? [n] 
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    checking file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
    checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
    checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
    checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
    checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
    checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
    checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
    checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
    checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css
```

The applied.patches.list contains:

```
2015-04-28 13:36:48 UTC | SUPEE-1533 | EE_1.13 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13_v1.patch
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php


2015-04-28 13:36:56 UTC | SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1 | a5c9abcb6a387aabd6b33ebcb79f6b7a97bbde77 | Thu Feb 5 19:14:49 2015 +0200 | v1.14.1.0..HEAD
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
patching file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php


2015-06-01 08:02:48 UTC | SUPEE-5994 | CE_1.6.0.0 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1.patch
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 386 (offset 113 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/messages.phtml
patching file get.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php


2015-07-08 16:33:33 UTC | SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1 | 7226d88b1eeb07a5fbc4e62be189a5219457cc14 | Mon Jun 22 16:32:26 2015 +0300 | 202596e441..7226d88b1e
patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 89 with fuzz 2 (offset -6 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 31 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
patching file errors/processor.php


-e -n 2016-05-03 11:23:18 UTC | SUPEE-6482 | CE_1.9.2.0 | v1 |  | Tue Jul 14 14:17:04 2015 +0300 |
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 209 (offset -24 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php


-e -n 2016-05-03 11:38:30 UTC | SUPEE-6788 | CE_1.9.0.1 | v1 | be76c3faa9d26b74a513463408211e9921b09341 | Fri Oct 23 14:59:13 2015 +0300 | ea98922
patching file .htaccess
patching file .htaccess.sample
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Soap/Server.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Exception.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file cron.php
patching file errors/processor.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php


-e 2016-10-27 17:52:09 UTC | SUPEE-1533 | EE_1.13 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13_v1.patch | REVERTED
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
```

I read this: [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems#answer-140701) but could not find the solution.

As it seems to affect all files of the patch, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you reverted the 1533 patch?

Comment: Yes I did, you see that on the last lines of the applied.patches.list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deleting all files at the error message that already exists. Also I had reapply the file with the error from the original package.

```
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
    Hunk #1 FAILED at 91.
    1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Revert SUPEE-1533 (if installed)
2. Install SUPEE-3941 (if not installed yet)
3. Install SUPEE-8788 v2

Answer (score 0):

Replace "downloader" folder with the same Magento Version and try again it's working fine.