# can not apply security patch 8788 v2 on magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, security, patches

this is output when I tried to apply 8788 v2

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.7.0.2_v2-2016-10-14-09-32-17\ \(2\).sh
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 373 (offset -19 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Cart.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
Hunk #7 succeeded at 506 (offset -5 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 1224 (offset -13 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 136 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 158 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 189 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 198 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 208 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #6 FAILED at 268.
Hunk #7 succeeded at 529 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 549 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 561 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 576 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #11 succeeded at 600 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #12 succeeded at 625 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #13 succeeded at 646 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #14 succeeded at 665 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #15 succeeded at 707 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #16 succeeded at 723 (offset -8 lines).
Hunk #17 succeeded at 754 with fuzz 2 (offset -24 lines).
Hunk #18 succeeded at 773 (offset -23 lines).
Hunk #19 FAILED at 811.
Hunk #20 succeeded at 837 (offset -21 lines).
Hunk #21 succeeded at 870 (offset -21 lines).
Hunk #22 succeeded at 893 (offset -21 lines).
Hunk #23 succeeded at 914 (offset -21 lines).
Hunk #24 succeeded at 992 with fuzz 2 (offset -21 lines).
2 out of 24 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Controller/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/reorder/sidebar.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tag/customer/view.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/wishlist/view.phtml
patching file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 154.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/Maged/View.php.rej
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
patching file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
can't find file to patch at input line 7570
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Parser.php lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|index 423902a..2c01684 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7582
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
|index caa979e..cd37804 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7598
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
|index d2a4937..c6c0221 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

Does anyone know how to pass ?

I did follow instruction from magento but still not solve the issue

Revert SUPEE-1533 (if installed)
Install SUPEE-3941 (if not installed yet)
Install SUPEE-8788 v2

Comment: did you edited the failed file in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/

Comment: there are no core changed. I installed another magento site on v1.7.0.2 and got same issue

Comment: are you getting same error in new magento 1.7.0.2?

Comment: yes i tested on new magento 1.7.0.2

Comment: simple, you have to apply SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7405 v1.1 and then apply 8788. You issues will get solved.

Comment: because 1.7.0.2 doesnot have above mentioned patches, hope this makes sense.

Comment: happy for your success, can i add it in your answer and will you approve it? so that others stuck in same issue might help

Comment: sure. i am trying to hightlight your answer anw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

Comment: no, issues are not same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying with Magento 1.9 or more, most of the SUPEE patches released are included by default.

Since you are trying 1.7.0.2, you need to install all those patches manually and then try latest 8788 patch.

So you have to apply `SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7405 v1.1` and then apply `8788`.

For more, just go through https://magento.com/tech-resources/download and download patches from there.