# Can't edit product after install Patch SUPEE-8788

Tags: magento-1.7, security, patches, supee-8788, supee-8788v2

After installation Patch SUPEE-8788 in my Magento 1.7.0.2 I have an error when I try to edit the product:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getUploaderConfig() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php on line 56

Comment: What page does this show up on?   When you go to "catalog" > "manage products?" and select a product?

Comment: Yes, Catalog --> Manage products

Comment: is your cache flushed and opcode cache?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixed - Image Upload issue after PATCH 8788 install of Magento version CE 1.7.0.2 - 1.9.2.4.**

**`I was able to fix it,Please Follow following instruction.`**

> Step >> 1: After installed security patch 8788 successfully, Please go to admin panel and **flush all Magento cache**. Then **Logout your Admin Panel** and **Relogin to Admin Panel**.
>
> Step >> 2: **Go to Index Management** and select all **reindex all data** after **flush all Magento cache once again**.
>
> Step >> 3: ***This very Important step,*** **Delete your browser cache(Ctrl+shift+Delete) history clear all browsing data from browser including cookies.**
>
> Step >> 4: Go to Catalog >> Product Management , **add new image of any product,now you can see everything work fine.**

Answer (score 8):

### Details about the problem

SUPEE-8788 replaces the old flash uploader with a new uploader system that sits in `Mage/Uploader` module.

By default 1.7.0.2 has got the following code in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php`

```
$this->setChild('uploader',
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/media_uploader')
);
$this->getUploader()->getConfig()
    ->setUrl(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/catalog_product_gallery/upload'))
    ->setFileField('image')
    ->setFilters(array(
        'images' => array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
            'files' => array('*.gif', '*.jpg','*.jpeg', '*.png')
        )
    ));
```

SUPEE-8788 replaces it with:

```
$this->setChild('uploader',
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_uploaderType)
);
$this->getUploader()->getUploaderConfig()
    ->setFileParameterName('image')
    ->setTarget(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/catalog_product_gallery/upload'));

$browseConfig = $this->getUploader()->getButtonConfig();
$browseConfig
    ->setAttributes(array(
        'accept' => $browseConfig->getMimeTypesByExtensions('gif, png, jpeg, jpg')
    ));
```

### Debugging the issue

According to the error you're getting, SUPEE-8788 was properly applied as your code is trying to call `getUploaderConfig` which is a new method introduced by the patch.

This method is called on `getUploader()` which returns `$this->getChild('uploader');`

This child corresponds to the child set at the beginning of the `_prepareLayout` method:

```
$this->setChild('uploader',
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_uploaderType)
);
```

In the case of this class, `$this->_uploaderType` is defined at the top:

```
protected $_uploaderType = 'uploader/multiple';
```

So the first thing I would check is to ensure that this file is available in your system, it should be under `app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php`

Two possible cases:

- it's not there. That would be definitely the cause of the problem but as SUPEE-8788 was applied it should be there. **Maybe you're using a versioning system and that file was not committed ?**
- it's there. In that case open it and ensure it's not empty or it doesn't look broken.

If that file is there and does not look broken, there's several things you can do:

First, try to **see what returns `get_class($this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_uploaderType))` . If it does not return `Mage_Uploader_Block_Multiple` that means you have another module that is using the `uploader` class name and thus must be refactored to be compatible with SUPEE-8788.**

**I know that the No Flash Uploader module has some compatibility issues with SUPEE-8788, see here: https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader/issues/18**

Then, if you still haven't found any issue, **you'll have to check that you don't have some custom adminhtml layout that remove the `uploader` child**, use the following command in `app/design/adminhtml/` to try to find out:

```
grep -ri "uploader" . | grep "layout"
```

In the list you get try to look for something like `<remove name="uploader" />`, that would be the cause.

Finally, the last thing that comes to my mind is that **you have Compilation enabled and you did not recompile after applying the patch**. To do so, go to System > Tools > Compilation and recompile.

Comment: recompile worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Every time you install the patches, check the correctness of the file permissions.

```
example: sudo chown www-data:www-data magento-folder
```