# Issues with Magento 1.9.3. or latest SUPEE-8788 upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, magento1.9.3.1

Just got notification re Magento 1.9.3.1 release. Before I go whack it up are there any potential issues I need to be aware of. I'm running Magento 1.9.2.4.

Should I apply SUPEE-8788 first or just upgrade to 1.9.3.1?

**Note:** This question is related to 1.9.3.1 and latest SUPEE-8788 patch which were released on 14th of Nov and is not related to older SUPEE-8788 (v1).

Comment: At this point (a day after release), I'd suggest just installing the SUPEE patch so you are secure :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Before you go and mark questions duplicate, pay attention and read it first.  This question is related to 1.9.3.1 and latest SUPEE-8788 patch which were released yesterday. The question you're referring to relates to 1.9.3.0 and older (v1) of SUPEE-8788

Answer (score 1):

The only known issue as of today according to the release notes is:

> You currently cannot upgrade to this version using Magento Connect
>   Manager. We expect to resolve this issue soon.