# Magento : 8788 patch error

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-8788

I installed magento 8788 patch to my site .Patch getting error like

```
    PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.0.1_v2-2016-10-14-09-37-14.sh: 14: 

    PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.0.1_v2-2016-10-14-09-37-14.sh: 127: not
    found PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.0.1_v2-2016-10-14-09-37-14.sh: 14:
    PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.0.1_v2-2016-10-14-09-37-14.sh: 127: not
    found PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.0.1_v2-2016-10-14-09-37-14.sh: 25:
    PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.0.1_v2-2016-10-14-09-37-14.sh: 0: not found

     Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
 /usr/bin/patch: **** malformed patch at line 5949: \F2rM]M\FD\BB\E8\F1\D6\F2&X㔮\81\FAv\93\83Q;r\C5N\99qJ\8E\89Y\E1\C4\DDI0\99Y\C9\C24\A9\80'\F1\CD\A5\8B\C49\F2.\BA\A0XAE\84Ǒ\89{\B6\E8\80ax!G\94\9A\C5I\E5\F9\C5q\9Du|\8C\CF\D7\C5թ\9F\93\AB\B3\B3\87|
                                                                                                               h\80\D3o\AAV@\A0\F5|\91 \D5g\C4H aꪭ\A3\E8Ю\F8\8B\80,I"\E0\A5ğ\AE\A6\FC\90.\95\E5 yI\B9I\\B1\84\97\84)\94X\C8
                                                                                \E1p\E1\E8\F2\90*\CDe\82q\E0K8<DqD\A8H;|\A9\00\81LD\90\8D\00\A1D$\8F\E1qe\94h\99$M\94J\CA\A7\A5\A0b\B1\90\C71q+9\F2\B21Ӓ\83\B1}xZO\82Ɂ+E3r\B1\FE\D5\C3z

   -e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
```

How to resolve this

Answer (score 3):

You need to zip the patch file first, upload the zip through FTP and then unzip it using SSH and bash the patch.

The patch will install without any problem.

Comment: Iam using in my local

Comment: Try same way in your local.

Comment: i dont have ftp

Comment: Make zip of your patch file and put that zip in local root of your project. Unzip and apply your patch.

Comment: I tried like that but its not applied @vishwas

Comment: Did you download the official patch from Magento directly? Have you tried downloading the patch again?
To know more about patch : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems

Comment: I downloaded from magento site only

Comment: need to install 1533 ?

Comment: Yes,
    revert SUPEE 8788 v1
    revert SUPEE 1533 (if installed)
    install SUPEE 3941 (if not installed)
    install SUPEE 8788 v2
The given link has all the information.

Comment: so need to install 3941 before that or 1533 ?

Comment: The process is not tedious. Please follow the step by step instructions. You will get your issue solved. 1533 needs to revert and 3941 needs to installed. 
Thank you.

Comment: I dont know revert means deleted ?

Comment: Yes, This is the doc to install and revert patches in Magento : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html#apply
Follow this. Mark this answer as completed once you solve your issue.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? which version of magento are you using?