# Magento patch SUPEE-10266-CE issue in product upload section missing

Tags: magento-1.8, patches, upload, supee-10266

We have applied `SUPEE-10266`-CE-1.8.1.0 Magento patch, but we getting issue in product edit page, on the product edit section product image upload section is missing.

We checked the system log, it gives error message like

> Not valid template
>   file:adminhtml/base/default/template/media/uploader.phtml

Please give valid feed back as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If your site has not been patched with latest security patches before **SUPEE-10266** 
Then it's possible the issue you are encountering is because of that.
**SUPEE 8788** patch makes changes to which template is pulled make sure you have that applied and then test your upload again.

Comment: All patches applied, we have getting the image tab looks like (https://prnt.sc/gmh7uq).

Comment: Make sure all three of these files have been removed from your site.
`skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf` `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf` `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf`
Also verify you were using the 8788 patch V3

Comment: Also this overflow article goes in depth an covers the issue you mention 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems