# SUPEE 10266 patch issue on Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, supee-10266, magereport

I have installed `SUPEE 10266` patch one of `Magento 1.7` site but MageReport still showing not patched. What could be the causes. I have also followed below link :

https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-10266-without-ssh/

This link shows that we need to flush opcode cache or restart web server. I just disabled the opcache but still not working. Can anyone tell me what should I need to do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For further info on this patch see [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

Check that you have no custom admin theme files overwriting the patched files for SUPEE-8788. The admin files affected are as follows:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/file.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtmlapp/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/toolbar.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login-simple.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
```

There are some minor changes in these files that need to be applied to your custom template files in order for MageReport to confirm the patch is in place.