# Product image Upload Issue in Magento 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

When i try to upload product image by clicking "Browse Files" button.
Image selection window is not showing.

## In browser console window i can see some errors.

[image]

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
(index):1480 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
(index):1434 Uncaught ReferenceError: media_gallery_contentJsObject is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):1434)
```

any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: I am face same issue in Magento 1.9.3.8 and I am use custom theme So can you suggest me where to add this content in adminhtml or frontend ?

Answer (score 1):

i found that magento 1.9.3.0 they remove the flash uploader so js file need to run uploader add these file in head.

```
<reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</file></action>
        <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</file></action>
        <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</file></action>
        <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js</file></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already i would suggest installing SUPEE-8788. This removes the flash uploader from the admin meaning that it uses the default html functionality instead. Most browsers block flash by default and you have to manually enable it for use on sites. This is to prevent vulnerabilities in flash.

Once the patch is applied, clear caches, log out/back into the admin and try again and you should be good to go.

Worth a read before applying: [Possible Issues with SUPEE-8788](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

Edit after more information provided.
If you've just updated Magento (Which you should have put in your original question) then,

1. Make sure you've cleared all caches, logged out of the admin and back in again
2. It looks like JS consolidation is enabled so it may be worth disabling that while debugging in System > Configuration > Developer > Javascript Setting.
3. Do you have the Creare SEO Extension? If so there is an incompatibility with it and SUPEE-8788 but there is a fix available for it here: https://github.com/adampmoss/CreareSEO/pull/78/files

Comment: Hi Dan Previously its working when magento version 1.9.0.1 .But after updating to 1.9.3.2 this issue came.

Comment: Hi @Hussain, I didn't know you had just upgraded, this gives some new information which I have now added to my answer, it's most likely point number 3 in the list. If this helps, please upvote my answer :)

Comment: Thanks . Product upload issue solved by adding all patches.

Comment: Awesome glad to here it. As my answered helped would you mind up voting it please so it may help other people in the future :)