# magento 1.9.3 Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1 even can't find keyword'TLSv1'

Tags: magento1.9.3

I find answer in

> [Magento 1.9.2 Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73748/magento-1-9-2-unknown-cipher-in-list-tlsv1)

But i can't find code like 
`$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');`in my `Curl.php`

Couldn't even find the **keyword** 'TLSv1'.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was removed in Magento 1.9.3

> Please check downloader\lib\Mage\HTTP\Client\Curl.php

```
- $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
- $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
+ $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
+ /**
+  * Use value from CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 (available since PHP 5.5)
+  *
+  * @link http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php
+  */
+
+ $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
```